# Multi column db insert form wordpress form

Tags: arrays, wordpress, insert

I am inserting form data into database.

My problem is that only one column gets populated, whereas 2nd column remains empty (null allowed).

Through following code I am able to insert data into `wp_my_table`, but only 1 column.  What i am doing wrong?

Also how do I insert Datepicker in order to select some values from Drop down menu ?

```
function elh_insert_into_db() {

global $wpdb;


// creates my_table in database if not exists
$table = $wpdb->prefix . "my_table"; 
$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (
    `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` text NOT NULL,
`Desc` text NULL,
UNIQUE (`id`)
) $charset_collate;";
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql );
// starts output buffering
ob_start();

?>
<form action="" method="post" id="v_form">
    <label for="visitor_name"><h3>Hello there! What is your name?</h3> 
</label>
    <input type="text" name="visitor_name" id="visitor_name" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="Desc" id="Desc" value="?php echo $name;?"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="submit" />
</form>

<?php
$html = ob_get_clean();
// does the inserting, in case the form is filled and submitted
if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) && $_POST["visitor_name"] != "" ) {
   global $wpdb;
 $table = $wpdb->prefix."my_table";

 $data=array(
'name'=> $_POST['visitor_name'] ,
'Desc'=> $_POST['Desc']
 );

$wpdb->insert($table,$data);



$wpdb->show_errors();
$wpdb->print_error();

    $html = "<p>Your name <strong>$name</strong> was successfully recorded. 
Thanks!!</p>";
}
// if the form is submitted but the name is empty
if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) && $_POST["visitor_name"] == "" )
    $html .= "<p>You need to fill the required fields.</p>";
// outputs everything
return $html;

}
// adds a shortcode you can use: [insert-into-db]
add_shortcode('elh-db-insert', 'elh_insert_into_db');
```

Comment: There's a typo in your code: `Desc="Desc"` should be `name="Desc"`.

Comment: Additionally value will always be wrong: `value="?php echo $name;?"` since those aren't valid PHP tags around there. This whole code needs some sanity checking before carrying on, you'll need to read through it and be careful with what you're typing.